# generate image links, with each image being able to display it's own version of a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to create a page that allows a user to edit information for different images. I got the edit button to appear under each image, but when it is clicked it only shows a dropdown menu for the first image on the page. Is it possible to pair the click event with the image it is next to?

I have this in a while loop:

```
$html.= 
                    "<td>\n
                    <table>\n
                    <tr>\n
                    <td id='browse-table' colspan=2><img class='img_grid' src='".$row['photo']."'></td>\n
                    <td></td>\n
                    </tr>\n
                    <tr class='browse_table_row' id='row'>\n
                    <td>M".$row['mustang_id']."</td><td rowspan=2 style='vertical-align:middle'>
                    <a class='edit_menu' onclick='editFunction()'>
                    <img class='menu_image'src='assets/img/circle-edit-article.png'></a>
                    <div class='edit-content' id='editdropdown'>
                    <a>Add to File</a>
                    <a href='edit_account.php?mid=$m_id&fname=$fname&initial=$initial&lname=$lname''>Edit</a>
                    <a>Delete</a>
                    <a>Download</a></td>\n
                    <td></td>\n
                    </tr>\n
                    <tr class='browse_table_row'>\n
                    <td nowrap id='selector'>".$row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name']."</td>\n
                    <td></td>\n
                    </tr>\n
                    </table>\n
                    </td>\n";
```

It loads the edit img for each picture, however the dropdown menu only appears for the first image.

Comment: Yup, it is definitely possible.

Comment: any pointers? I'm really hung up on this issue.

Comment: Adding some form of code would help...

Comment: @HanYolo473 Something like this: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.edit_menu').click(function() {
var active_menu = $(this).children('.edit-content');


$('.edit-content').not(active_menu).hide();


active_menu.toggle("show");
});
```

Got it to work by doing this.